# How to set the <title> tag from component code?

Tags: joomla-3.x

How do I set the `<head>`'s `<title>` tag in MVC component's code? I know the page title (which would appear on top of the page) can be set in several ways but the `<title>` seems to be only settable from menu item properties. I need to set `<title>` without using menu items (from component code).

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=setTitle+is%3Aquestion.  If not please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Joomla's `setTitle()` method, like so:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

Factory::getDocument()->setTitle('My Custom Title');
```

Comment: It seems to set the tile on the site but not the <title> tag contents in the <head> section of the page.

Comment: @ed22 - Working perfectly fine for me. The browser sets the page title based on the `<title>` value, so I'm not sure how the tab shows the title but the `<title>` isn't updating.